# Proxy on raspberry pi running Android

Tags: android, proxy, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running Android 3.1 and its connected to the internet using a Ethernet wired connection. How do I set proxy to use wired connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use this: (your proxy is mynetworkproxy:9000)

```
setprop global_http_proxy_host mynetworkproxy
setprop global_http_proxy_port 9000
```

After doing an adb shell to get access to the device's console.

If that doesn't work and you have root access you can manually change the setting in the settings.db file. See here http://elinux.org/Android_Networking in the "Configuring a web proxy" section for more info.